# Native SQL query to Spring JPA named query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am having below query.

```
SELECT zip, primary_city, latitude, longitude,
      111.045* DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(latpoint))
                 * COS(RADIANS(latitude))
                 * COS(RADIANS(longpoint) - RADIANS(longitude))
                 + SIN(RADIANS(latpoint))
                 * SIN(RADIANS(latitude)))) AS distance_in_km
 FROM zip
 JOIN (
     SELECT  42.81  AS latpoint,  -70.81 AS longpoint
   ) AS p ON 1=1
 ORDER BY distance_in_km
 LIMIT 15
```

When I execute the above query in sql editor i am getting zip,primary_city, latitude, longitude ,distance_in_km from zip table.

I need to use the same in my JPA repository.I tried using named query but it shows Validation failed exception.Also In my entity class zip.java having only 
zip, primary_city, latitude, longitude(four attributes).I need to decide how to capture distance_in_km which comes from resultset 
Kindly help me how to achieve the same in Spring JPA

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to set the [nativeQuery](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html#nativeQuery--) flag, because this is not a JPQL query.
2. The SQL query uses named parameters for `:latitude`, when there's no such parameter given to the query.
3. You missed the "+" sign on the 5th line of your query:

   ```
   +"*COS(RADIANS(longpoint) - RADIANS (height))"
   +" SIN (RADIANS (latpoint))"
   ```

should be:

```
    +"*COS(RADIANS(longpoint) - RADIANS (height))"
    +" + SIN (RADIANS (latpoint))"
```

4. The JOIN condition doesn't take any table, so I am not sure what you wanted to do JOIN with.

You query should be written as:

```
SELECT 
    code,
    name,
    length,
    height, 
    111.045* DEGREES (ACOS(COS(RADIANS(latpoint)) * COS (RADIANS(length)) * COS(RADIANS(longpoint) - RADIANS (height)) + SIN (RADIANS (latpoint)) *SIN (RADIANS(length)))) As distance_in_km,
    latitude AS latpoint, 
    longitute AS longpoint
FROM place
ORDER BY distance_in_km
LIMIT 5
```

Never underestimate the power of code indentation. Some other develop might have to maintain this query, so always write your queries as you want to find them.

Comment: The distance_in_km will come as a result of query execution.So how to I define those variable in entity class

Comment: You need to use a [projection instead](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Server/1.0/html/Hibernate_Core_Reference_Guide/querycriteria-projection.html). It's easier if you use a DTO, but you can also use an entity (although you'd have to select more columns than you probably need).

Comment: distance_in_km column is not at all there in the table.It will come when we execute the query based on the calculation.So do i need to define one more entity for resulset or is there any other way to define

Comment: You can use @Formula for it.